# How to check number exists in Firebase Database? - react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native

I use react native through firebase database
I have a database creating products each product has a number
I want to take a number and compare it with the product number
And if there is then I want to get a product

the function its give me my correct name but where i use it on render its not found the variable (name)

```
getAllContact = async key => {
let barCodeData2 = this.props.navigation.state.params.barcodeData
let self = this;
let contactRef = firebase.database().ref()
contactRef.on("value", dataSnapsot => {
  if (dataSnapsot.val()) {
    let contactResult = Object.values(dataSnapsot.val())
    let contactKey = Object.keys(dataSnapsot.val())
    contactKey.forEach((value, key) => {
      contactResult[key]["key"] = value
    })
    self.setState({
      fname: contactResult.fname,
      data: contactResult.sort((a, b) => {
        var nameA = a.barcode
        var nameB = barCodeData2
        const name = a.fname
        console.log(`${nameA} What numers issssssss`);
        if (nameA == nameB) {
          alert(`${name} ........`)
          console.log(`${nameA == nameB}is Equqlqlqlql`);
          return name
        }
      }),
    })
  }
})
```

}

```
 render() {
let t=this.state.name
alert(`${t} how?`)// is give Not found
```

// let d = this.props.navigation.state.params.barcodeData

```
return (
```

)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try such a comparison query i.e.

```
let ref = firebase.firestore();
    ref.collection('zoo')
    .where("id", "==", myID)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snap.empty); //this will denote if results are empty
      snapshot.forEach(snap => {
        console.log(snap.exists); //alternatively this will also tell you if it is empty
      })
    })
```

Comment: That's my code.
I was able to do a function that you pull out and check. And she works.
Now I want to activate it and get the name

Comment: In the code I wrote, if the product exists just try `snap.data()` after the `console.log(snap.exists)`

Answer (score 0):

well what you can do is run query based on you product no and if there's a product you will a product if there's none you will get an empty array.

read firebase documentation on queries

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query